# Online Code Review Scripts Like Udacity

Tags: grading, programming, lesson-review

Please, can anyone recommend a simple online code review scripts/website similar to udacity. Instructor upload students code to the scripts, they add inline comments and can send the URL to the student. I need something very simple. No need for auto-grading. If not available, is there any library I can use to build my own?

Thanks

Attached is the screenshots for clarification.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to [cseducators.se]! For those unfamiliar with the Udacity code review process (such as myself), could you give a bit of information about what it's like? You'll be more likely to get helpful answers this way.

Comment: I've been thinking a bit about it, and I have some possible ideas, but I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Could you edit your question and clarify?

Comment: @BenI. I attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

My company has a training program for software engineering interns. A computer science problem is given to them that they have to code. Every individual intern is going to create a PR to one of our company's repository. Without merging the PR, an instructor can do a code review and add comments, just like Udacity's. IMO, [GitHub](https://github.com/features/code-review/) is better for code review than Udacity. It has everything that Udacity has to offer and much more.

Also, they are learning the GitHub workflow which may be helpful in companies that use GitHub (like mine).